# How to force ocamlbuild using already built obj-files if two different targets compiled serially

Tags: ocamlbuild

I have two different ml-targets, which should be compiled to native code. Both targets are sharing some modules.

The problem is, if I run "ocamlbuild targetA" the modules C, D and E are compiled to object code. But when I run than "ocamlbuild targetB" the modules D and E will be recompiled again.

How could I force that the recompilation of modules D and E (which are shared by targetA and targetB) will be avoided?

I am using ocamlbuild 3.11.2.

Any hints?

Bye Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Would using a single invocation of ocamlbuild work for you?  That is, run "ocamlbuild targetA targetB" or use an .itarget.

Comment: support for itarget seems to be buggy and is reported to ocamlbuild maintainer. I must rethink your other suggestions, because would be hard to use it in makefile. I will test it soon.